# How to setup Row/Column Definitions in Xamarin.Forms Xaml?

Tags: grid, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I managed to setup rows and columns from the code but couldn't move this settings to xaml:

```cs
grid.RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection { 
    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) } 
};
grid.ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection { 
    new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) } 
};
```

The following doesn't work:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="grid" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    ...
</Grid>
```

From the [documentation](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aXamarin.Forms.Grid) I managed to fetch only c# implementation

Comment: Can you define "it doesn't work" ? Your xaml looks valid, and it's the right way to do it.

Comment: it doesn't give all the screen space to grid content with row=0 and col=0. As instead content is shifted to the top-left corner of the form. Though if I use definition from code - if works and it gives all the space to inner controls which are goes to the center

Comment: this thing is supposed to work. can you post more complete example, code and xaml of what you're doing. thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also get the same behaviour (does not fill and expand) for a grid with a single cell (1 row / column, although I am not sure why we would ever need a grid with a single cell full size of screen), but it seems to work fine for a 2 x 2, 3 x 3 cell grid (have not tried others yet).

The Height="*" and Width="*" attributes are required in Xamarin Forms although I "think" they are not needed in WPF as the default assumes this is the case.

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="1"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="2"></Button>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample

```xml
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Label Text="Top Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
  <Label Text="Top Right" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
  <Label Text="Bottom Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
  <Label Text="Bottom Right" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```